# Erasing zeros from the vector element in Rcpp

Tags: r, performance, vector, subset, rcpp

I wrote the following code to erase zeros from the vector. I use the `erase(i)` function from the Rcpp library.

```c
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector erase_zero(NumericVector x) {
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    if (x[i] == 0) {
      x.erase(i);
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Everything is fine, now the problem is the output of the function, i.e.

```r
> erase_zero(c(0,1,2,3,0))
[1] 1 2 3
> erase_zero(c(0,0,1,2,3,0,0))
[1] 0 1 2 3 0
> erase_zero(c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0))
[1] 0 1 2 3 0
> erase_zero(c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0))
[1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 0
```

I don't know why this is happening.

after reading all the answers below, I simply tried the speed test

```
> microbenchmark(erase_zero(s), erase_zero1(s), erase_zero_sugar(s))
Unit: microseconds
                expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
       erase_zero(s) 19.311 21.2790 22.54262 22.181 22.8780 35.342   100
      erase_zero1(s) 18.573 21.0945 21.95222 21.771 22.4680 36.490   100
 erase_zero_sugar(s)  1.968  2.0910  2.57070  2.296  2.5215 24.887   100
```

`erase_zero1` is Roland's first code. Also, ThomasIsCoding's R base is more efficient than all.

Comment: Why do we need loop?

Comment: @zx8754 You always need a loop. It might be hidden behind some sugar syntax but it must be there.

Comment: You can take a look at my latest benchmarking, it seems the base R is already efficient enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`erase` changes the size of the vector. This gives the expected output.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector erase_zero(NumericVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.size();
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (x[i] == 0) {
      x.erase(i);
      i--;
      n--;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

/*** R
erase_zero(c(0,1,2,3,0))
erase_zero(c(0,0,1,2,3,0,0))
erase_zero(c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0))
erase_zero(c(0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0))
*/
```

However, you should just use some Rcpp sugar. It is more efficient:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector erase_zero_sugar(NumericVector x) {
  return x[x != 0];
}
```

You should also read [Why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

Comment: Thanks! Your sugar code is more efficient than the other two valid answers. I tried a speed test, and your solution is the winner.

Answer (score 3):

The size of your `x` is dynamically changing when committing `erase`. you can try `while` like below

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector erase_zero(NumericVector x) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x.size()) {
        if (x[i]==0) {
            x.erase(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

## Example output

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector erase_zero(NumericVector x) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x.size()) {
        if (x[i]==0) {
            x.erase(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
"
)

x <- c(0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0)
erase_zero(x)
```

and you will see

```
[1] 5 1 2 3 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a benchmarking with a bunch of `Rcpp` approaches vs the base R subsetting, and you will see that **the base R approach `x[x!= 0]` is the most efficient already**.

## Rcpp codes

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f0(NumericVector x) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x.size()) {
        if (x[i]==0) {
            x.erase(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
"
)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f1(NumericVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.size();
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (x[i] == 0) {
      x.erase(i);
      i--;
      n--;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
"
)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f2(NumericVector x) {
  R_xlen_t n = x.size();
  NumericVector res;
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (x[i] != 0) {
      res.push_back(x[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
"
)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f3(NumericVector x) {
  return x[x != 0];
}
"
)
```

and the code for comparison

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(0:5, 1e5, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark(
    fwhile = f0(x),
    ffor1 = f1(x),
    ffor2 = f2(x),
    fsuger = f3(x),
    baseR = x[x != 0],
    unit = "relative",
    times = 10L
)
```

## Output

```
Unit: relative
   expr         min         lq        mean      median          uq         max
 fwhile 4574.766987 3877.57877 2491.634303 3541.983516 2149.808409 1152.438181
  ffor1 4204.952786 3690.07333 2340.518164 3275.927345 2060.156985 1117.993311
  ffor2 8270.203280 7302.53550 4754.341310 6746.984478 4158.206201 2221.732950
 fsuger    1.236079    1.13896    1.299927    1.110674    1.091769    1.579036
  baseR    1.000000    1.00000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
 neval
    10
    10
    10
    10
    10
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It's really interesting!

Comment: @ManAni I think some of the basic functionalities in base R are optimized, so not necessary to rebuild the wheels in Rcpp unless you really need to adapt them to your specific use cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, actually, I need this code for a bigger code which is in Rcpp.